# Modal inside a loop wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've been reading about this and trying different things without success. I have a loop with different posts and I have a button that when I press on it there is a modal opened to share the post.

I was trying to add a unique ID to each modal so when I click on it open the correct modal with the correct share links. However is not working.

This is the code I am using inside my modal:

```
<a id="myBtn-<?php echo $post_id; ?>" href="#"><span class="share-text">Compartir</span></a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal-<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="modal-share">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-share-content">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="modal-share-header">
    <span class="close-share">&times;</span>
    <h2>¿Dónde quieres compartirlo?</h2>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <div class="date"><?php 
        $dateformatstring = "D d M";
        $unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('fecha'));
        echo date_i18n($dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp);
        ?></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul>
      <li class="mobile-only"><a class="share-whatsapp" target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li class="mobile-only"><a class="share-messenger" target="_blank" href="fb-messenger://share?link=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> 
      <li class="desktop-only"><a class="share-messenger" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=1385443625036469&redirect_uri=http://www.fanonfire.com/gracias-por-compartir/&display=popup&link=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> 
      <li class="fb"><a class="share-facebook" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li> 
      <li class="tw"><a class="share-twitter" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;lang=es&amp;text=Vente a <?php the_title(); ?> en Madrid via @fanonfire"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>  
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal-<?php echo $post_id; ?>');
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn-<?php echo $post_id; ?>");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close-share")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
} 
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

So as I understand when I click on the for example myBtn-1 I must get the modal myModal-1. However I get always the last modal of all my available posts and looking at my code is "working fine".

Any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add the `$post_id` to your `var`s.
Right now you're overwriting `btn` in every subsequent script (assuming you are echoing thatz script inside your post_id loop).

However this entire approach is bad. Use jQuery to assign the same code to all your links. In the link code, find the elements by going up to the container `<div>`, then back to the classes.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".showModal").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $parent = $(this).parent();
      $(".modal-share").hide();
      $parent.find(".modal-share").show();
    });
    $(".close-share").click(function(e) {
     $(this).parent().hide();
    });
    $(document).click(function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).hasClass("modal-share"))
        $(".modal-share").hide();
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.post {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: relative
}

.modal-share {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: none
}
.close-share {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post">
  <p>
    Post One
  </p>
  <a class="showModal" href=""><span class="share-text">Compartir</span></a>
  <div class="modal-share">Modal One<span class="close-share">X</span></div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <p>
    Post Two
  </p>
  <a class="showModal" href=""><span class="share-text">Compartir</span></a>
  <div class="modal-share">Modal Two<span class="close-share">X</span></div>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <p>
    Post Three
  </p>
  <a class="showModal" href=""><span class="share-text">Compartir</span></a>
  <div class="modal-share">Modal Three<span class="close-share">X</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that in my code but is not working inside the loop. I added the class to the link: class="showModal" and the function at the end of the document outside of the loop. Is that correct? Or the script should be also inside the loop? The css is similar that the one I have.

Comment: The css shouldn't matter. The script goes outside the loop, yes. Check your browser console. Are you getting any errors? The script assumes a pre-existing jQuery, usually that's available on Wordpress.

Comment: Ok, my problem was that the modal was not after the link, was outside the DIV. Now is working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple:

1. add the ID to your button as `data-target="#ViewDevice-<?php the_ID(); ?>`
2. then add the same id to your modal like `id="ViewDevice-<?php the_ID(); ?>`

The full code example is below

```html
 <button type="button" class="defaultbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ViewDevice-<?php the_ID(); ?>" >open my unique modal thanks to @jerryurenaa</button>



<div class="modal fade" id="ViewDevice-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg ">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">title goes here or make it dynamic :D </h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
     <p>make content dynamic as needed</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
     
        <button href="/" class="btn btn-primary"> website</button> 
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```